# How to populate a new foreign key table with existing data?

Tags: sql, mysql, foreign-keys

I am cleaning my database structure : I have several table `A`, `B` and `C` that contained all the same columns `date1`, `date2` and `date3`.
I would like to create a new table `date` containing these 3 columns and use it as a foreign key in `A`, `B` and `C`.

The creation of the table is easy, but I have no clue as to how to initially populate the table `date` so that I don't lose the information I already have about `date1`, `date2` and `date3`.

Assuming every line of `A`, `B` and `C` must be linked to one line in `date`, is there a way to do this in sql ?

**Example input :**

Table A :

```
id, date1, date2, date3, x, y

1, 01/01/2023, 05/05/2023, 01/01/2023, 1, 2
2, 01/01/2023, 05/05/2023, 01/01/2023, 1, 2
3, 22/05/2023, 11/05/2023, 19/12/2023, 1, 2
```

Table B :

```
id, date1, date2, date3, x

1, 01/01/2020, 05/05/2020, 01/01/2020, 1
```

Table C :

```
id, date1, date2, date3

1, 01/01/2020, 05/05/2020, 01/01/2020, 1
```

**Expected output :**

Table `date` (note that identical lines are expected) :

```
id, date1, date2, date3
1, 01/01/2023, 05/05/2023, 01/01/2023
2, 01/01/2023, 05/05/2023, 01/01/2023
3, 22/05/2023, 11/05/2023, 19/12/2023
4, 01/01/2020, 05/05/2020, 01/01/2020
5, 01/01/2020, 05/05/2020, 01/01/2020
```

Table A :

```
id, x, y, date_id
1, 1, 2, 1
2, 1, 2, 2
3, 1, 2, 3
```

Table B :

```
id, x, date_id

1, 1, 4
```

Table C :

```
id, date_id

1, 5
```

Comment: To clarify please add sample data and expected outcome as text.

Comment: I would do it with two `INSERT` statements per table: one to insert date from table `A` into table `date`, one to insert newly-created foreign key value from table `date` into table `A`.  Then repeat for the other tables.  If you share more details of your table structure and data then we might make this more specific.

Comment: Also, although it's perfectly allowable to call a table `date`, the risk of confusion with the MySQL function `DATE()` is high - I suggest calling the table something more descriptive and distinct from standard MySQL function names.

Comment: @P.Salmon you're right, I added an example input/output

Comment: @RobEyre Right, we actually do not plan to call it date, I'm just simplifying everything here so that the problem at hand is easier to grasp

Comment: @RobEyre Your solution seems to be alright, maybe adding a `a_id` temporary column in `date` in order to avoid having dates with several children

Comment: To get the list of existing dates that need to be populated into your new table, just take the 3 date columns from each existing table and union them together, inserting the result into your new table

Answer (score 0):

We often face scenarios when we have to map repeating text  in a table to id (use of definition table). I usually do it in 2 steps.

1. Get distinct values and insert into newly created def table.
2. Then join target table with def table using repeating text column to update the ids in the target table.

In your scenario, it would be like:

1. Get distinct date1, date2, date3 from all target tables using union to populate def table
2. Then write an update query by joining target table with def table on columns date1, date2, date3

PS: If I have a large table then I would do it in chunks by applying appropriate where filters.

**Edit:**
I am not sure why you are saving duplicate rows in date table if you don't have any other column? Anyways, in that case you can:

1. Get date1, date2, date3 + primary key of target table + table_name (source column which will be removed after update) and insert into date table.
2. Then join target table with def table using primary key of target table and use of where clause to filter out rows of target table name.